# The ListView LayoutCreated Event Is Not Fired After Handling ItemCommand

Tags: asp.net, listview

I am trying to update controls in the  of a ListView control after handling the ItemCommand event.

My ListView displays line items of a purchase order in the  as html table rows along with a TextBox to enter a new quantity and a Button to update the quantity. My ListView then displays sub-totals, discounts, and a grand total of the line items above in the  as html table rows as well. On initial load, I set the values of the controls in the ListView's  in the LayoutCreated event handler.

When a new quantity is entered and the button to update is clicked, I handled the event in the ItemCommand event handler. I update the quantity of the specific line item. I then re-bind my ListView to the underlying collection and call DataBind(). The problem is, LayoutCreated is *not* fired this time around, only on initial load.

My work around is to just pull those controls out of the  and address them as static controls, but I like having them inside  because my table markup can be fully contained in the  and my  can show cleanly without having to juggle the static controls' display properties.

Is what I am asking possible? Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I wonder if handling the `DataBound` event (instead of the `LayoutCreated` event), and setting the values there, would solve your problem.  I'm not confident enough to put that as an answer, but it's something to consider =)

Comment: Thank you jadarnel27. WIN! I switched my LayoutCreated event handler code out to a DataBound event handler, and I am now getting the desired behavior. How do I vote/mark your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd reccomend handling the `DataBound` event of the `ListView` (instead of the `LayoutCreated` event), and setting the values there.  That will get called everytime you re-bind the `ListView`, as well as when it loads for the first time, which (from your description) is what you want to do.